# Rails Display post according to timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am noob in Rails i was following rails official documentation for creating blog, after creating the blog with post and comment controller i want to add some way to display the post according to time-stamp i.e. the post which is created last or someone had commented on that post is displayed on top of the list. Please suggest a way or some gem to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `order` of activerecord. Assuming your blog model is `Blog`

```
Blog.order("updated_at DESC")
```

Check the [Tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering)

You can also create a [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)

Comment: this will only order by creation of post. what if someone comment on a post ?? how can i show that post on top which is commented by latest

Comment: It will order by modified time not by creation time. If you allow update the parent's (`Blog`) `updated_at` when new comment is added, this is simple. Put in your comment model `after_save do
  self.blog.touch
end`. Otherwise you will have to use joins.